# How to create a PR that creates a new branch that does not merge to main branch

Tags: git, github

In my local repo there are 2 branches that I always keep:

- main
- boilerplate

The boilerplate branch was created off the very first commit in this repo and it contains these files which consist of generic code -

```
Modules/0000_Object_Description/TableScript.sql
Modules/0000_Object_Description/ViewScript.sql
Modules/0000_Object_Description/LoadScript.sql
```

The files in this branch are used to create new modules for features as they're developed.

Here's my workflow in this repo to create a new feature module:

```
git switch main
git checkout -b feature/0750_Inventory
git restore --source boilerplate Modules/0000_Object_Description
```

Then the copied boilerplate files for the feature being developed are renamed. In this example, they become:

```
Modules/0750_Inventory/TableScript.sql
Modules/0750_Inventory/ViewScript.sql
Modules/0750_Inventory/LoadScript.sql
```

This all works fine.

Now, other project contributors would like the boilerplate files to be accessible in the central repository.

I executed the command: `git push origin boilerplate`. When I looked in Github it wanted to create a pull request to merge the boilerplate branch to the main branch.

How can I get the boilerplate branch to exist in the central repo without merging it to the main branch?

Comment: The offering by GitHub to create a GitHub PR to `main` is just that: an *offering*, not a requirement.  GitHub do this for you because most users want it done for them. As far as I know, there is no way to turn off the offer, but you can simply *ignore* it. (Using an "orphan branch" for these files might turn it off, since such a branch can't be merged easily through the GitHub web interface.)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the boilerplate branch to exist in the central repo without merging it to the main branch?

You would do `git push --set-upstream origin boilerplate`

> when I looked in Github it wanted to create a pull request to merge the boilerplate branch to the main branch

This part sounds suspicious as I'm not aware of the functionality which would lead to this behaviour.